# AttributeError - 'Div' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash, attributeerror

I am trying to run this code:

```
def parse_data(contents, filename):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV or TXT file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
        elif 'txt' or 'tsv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user upl, delimiter = r'\s+'oaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')), delimiter = r'\s+')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            'There was an error processing this file.'
        ])

    return df

def update_graph(contents, filename):
    fig = {
        'layout': go.Layout(
            plot_bgcolor=colors["graphBackground"],
            paper_bgcolor=colors["graphBackground"])
    }

    if contents:
        contents = contents[0]
        filename = filename[0]
        df = parse_data(contents, filename)
        df = df.set_index(df.columns[0])
        fig['data'] = df.iplot(asFigure=True, kind='scatter', mode='lines+markers', size=1)


    return fig
```

And get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py", line 93, in update_graph
    df = df.set_index(df.columns[0])
AttributeError: 'Div' object has no attribute 'set_index'
```

Any ideas what might be wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The error must be in your parse_data function. Could you please add the code for that section?

Comment: Hi Illustrati, I have just added it! Hopefully, it helps.. I have no idea how to solve it!

Comment: It looks like your try/catch is catching an error. You return a `div` from that, and that's why you get the error. Maybe check your console for the error that you're printing out.

Comment: in `parse_data` you have `return html.Div()` so when you get error then you get `df = html.Div()` and later you try to do `df.set_index()` which means `html.Div().set_index()`. You should check what you have in `df` after `df = parse_data()` and skip rest of code. Maybe better use `return None` and after `df = parse_data()` do `if df is None: html.Div(...) else df.set_index()`

Comment: BTW: it has to be `elif ('txt' in filename) or ('tsv' in filename):` but I would rather use `if filename.lower().endswith( ('txt', 'tsv') )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All problem is with your `parse_data()`. If it can't read file then it runs `return html.Div()` so running `df = parse_data()` means `df = html.Div()` and later you don't check if you really get data in `df` and `df.set_index()` means `html.Div().set_index()`.

Maybe better use `return None` and check this after `df = parse_data()`

```
def parse_data(contents, filename):
    # ... code ...

    try:

       # ... code ...

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None

    return df
```

and later

```
    df = parse_data(contents, filename)

    if df is None:
        html.Div(['There was an error processing this file.'])
    else:
        df = df.set_index(df.columns[0])
        fig['data'] = df.iplot(asFigure=True, kind='scatter', mode='lines+markers', size=1)
```

---

But this still can have problem with `fig['data']` when it can't read file.

I can't test your code but maybe it should do assign `Div` to `fig['data']`

```
if df is None:
    fig['data'] = html.Div(['There was an error processing this file.'])
else:
    df = df.set_index(df.columns[0])
    fig['data'] = df.iplot(asFigure=True, kind='scatter', mode='lines+markers', size=1)
```